# Unable to find pyspark testing module

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Although, in source code in github I see pyspark.testing module being present, however, my local environment is throwing error that pyspark.testing is not found.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/testing/sqlutils.py#L27
(Source Code)

Have installed pyspark as
pip install pyspark

Folder structure inside pyspark module in conda environment:

```
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                bin
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                cloudpickle
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                data
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                examples
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                jars
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                licenses
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                ml
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                mllib
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                pandas
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                python
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                resource
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                sbin
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                sql
d----            6/2/2022 12:15 PM                streaming
```

Although all other folders from git repo are present, however, testing folder is not present.

Installed pyspark version

```
pyspark==3.2.1
```